# Android: How to retrive the particular row or item 's view in a recyclerview based on the adapter position?

Tags: android, animation, mobile, android-recyclerview

I m having a recycler view with a list of items. I need to have programmatically scroll to the position of the particular item in recycler view This i had achieved  by using

```
final RecyclerView.SmoothScroller smoothScroller = new
                LinearSmoothScroller(getActivity()) {
                    @Override protected int getVerticalSnapPreference() {
                        return LinearSmoothScroller.SNAP_TO_START;
                    }
                };
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

                        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE ) {
                            Log.e ("Recycler :", "Scroll changed IDLE");
                            if (recyclerView.getChildAt(pos) != null) {
                                View view = recyclerView.getChildViewHolder(recyclerView.getChildAt(pos)).itemView;
                                Log.e ("Child :", "Not null");
                                view.startAnimation(fadeOutAnimation);
                                //recyclerView.getChildAt(pos).setAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
                            } else {
                                Log.e ("Child : ", "Null");
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                        Log.e ("OnScrolled", "Scrol");
                    }
                });
```

But after after scrolling to that particular position i need give Fade in animation to that particular view I not getting success in doing this.

So if i want to give fadein animation to the 3rd item then initially it will scroll to that position and it will not animate.

Again if i want to animate to 3rd position it will animate to the 3rd visible item in recycler view not the 3rd item adapter

```
recyclerView.getChildAt(pos)
```

Is the proper way to retrieve the item at the position?